# What is writing to my /dev/dm-2 Volume?

Tags: logs, lvm, audit, device-mapper

I'm running a STIG version of RHEL, and I’m having trouble figuring out how all of my logical volumes map.

`/dev/mapper/vg1_audit` seems to point to `/dev/dm-2`

`/dev/vg1/lv_audit` also seems to map to `/dev/dm-2`

Running an `lsblk` shows that these volumes are mounted on `/var/log/audit`, but I’m seeing different results when I run `cat` on each.

When I `cat /var/log/audit.log` and `audit.log.1`, they’re blank (since I cleared them with `truncate`). However, running a `cat /dev/mapper/vg1_audit` and `/dev/dm-2`, it prints out a huge file with log data.

I’m not sure where this log is being stored or who’s writing to it. I also can't clear it using `truncate`, FWIW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `/dev/mapper/vg1_audit` seems to point to `/dev/dm_2`
>
> `/dev/vg1/lv_audit` also seems to map to `/dev/dm_2`

That's correct (with some typos), the `/dev/dm-2` is the [device mapper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_mapper) device which represents the logical volume `lv_audit`. `/dev/mapper/vg1-lv_audit` and `/dev/vg1/lv_audit` are just user friendly symlinks created by LVM.

> When I cat `/dev/var/log/audit.log`

`/dev/var/log/audit.log` doesn't make sense. `/dev` holds files representing the block devices, not the content of the device, that's what mountpoints are for, so the content is in `/var/log/audit`.

> However, running a cat `/dev/mapper/vg1_audit` and `/dev/dm_2`, it prints out a huge file with log data.

Running `cat /dev/dm-2` reads directly from the block device so you get the entire raw content of the device. `truncate` does not overwrite the file with zeros, it just changes its size so the data is still physically present on the disk until overwritten by something else. This is also what happens when you simply remove a file -- the data is still there and can be recovered until overwritten but the file no longer exists (or takes up space in case of `truncate`).

Comment: Doh! fixed typos. So what you're saying is that they're actually all one in the same (in terms of what writes to it), it's just that the audit logs are sort of a pointer to this disk space? So because I told the log it was 0 bytes, it just tells me it's empty, but I didn't actually delete the contents, they're all just stored in /dev/dm-2 and flagged as "future writeable space"? Sorry for my non-technical phrasing. Is it possible to clear it?

Comment: Yes, when you remove a file (same applies to truncating it to 0), filesystem just marks the space as free without actually overwriting the disk space with zeroes. So you can still read the data if you read from the disk directly (this is how data recovery tools work). If you read `/var/log/audit/audit.log` you ask the filesystem to read the file, which is now empty. If you read `/dev/dm-2` you are reading directly from the disk, where the data still is present until overwritten.